# Access interface of a custom eclipse plugin at runtime

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

hi stackoverflow community,

I have a custom eclipse plugin which defines the interface

```
public interface IMatchResultEvaluator {

    String evaluateMatchResult(MatchResult match);
}
```

.

Now I want the user to be able to implement this interface at runtime. So I want him to be able to write the code for the evaluateMatchResult method via a gui, then I want to compile his class with the Java 6 compiler api and then I want to load the class using reflection. 
In order to do this, I would need access to the IMatchResultEvaluator class at runtime. How to do that?

With the help of svasa's answer I tried already to invoke the javac compiler that way

```
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("com.florian.regexfindandreplace");
   String bundleLocation = bundle.getLocation();
   String[] locs = bundleLocation.split("reference:file:/");
   String interfaceFileLoc = locs[1] + bundle.getEntry( "/IMatchResultEvaluator" );

    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(javaCompiler.getAbsolutePath(), "-classpath",
interfaceFileLoc,   myImplFile.getAbsolutePath());
            Process p = processBuilder.start();
```

but that didn't compile because the symbol IMatchResultEvaluator wasn't found. 
What do I need to change here?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: How does the GUI look like ? It contains text input for the body of implementation for `evaluateMatchResult`?

Comment: Yes, you got the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I would go about something like this : 
I am assuming user would enter only the body of implementation in the GUI,
and you know full path of the interface.

```
try 
{
    Class<?> IMatchResultEvaluator = Class.forName( "UI.IMatchResultEvaluator" );
    String userText = "My Implementation";
    String MyImplClass = "public class MyImplClass implements " + IMatchResultEvaluator.getSimpleName() + "\n" + "{" + "\n" +  "@Override String evaluateMatchResult( MatchResult match )" + "\n" + "{ " + "\n" + userText + "\n" + " }" + "\n" +  "}";


    File myImplFile = createMyImplClass( MyImplClass );
    if (myImplFile != null & myImplFile.exists())
    {
        compileClass( myImplFile );
    }

} 
catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

private File createMyImplClass( String MyImplClass )
{
   File file = new File( "MyImplClass.java" );

   //write to file from string MyImplClass
   return file;
}

private void compileClass( File file )
{
   //Get full path of interface
   Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("<your plugin qualified name>");
   String bundleLocation = bundle.getLocation();
   String[] locs = bundleLocation.split("reference:file:/");
   String interfaceFileLoc = locs[1] + bundle.getEntry( "/IMatchResultEvaluator" );


   //Compile class

}
```

Comment: In the compileClass method, I need to tell the javac.exe where to find the IMatchResultEvaluator interface, so I need to set the classpath correctly. How to do this?

Comment: I hope you know the fully qualified name of IMatchResultEvaluator to pass it into `Class.forName(...)` , about the full path of the interface to tell javac.exe, please see updated `compileClass` method, but I thought you already have an interface class loaded , no?

Comment: please post what `locs[1]` shows in your env, also you don't need `interfacefileloc` in classpath, just `locs[1]`

Comment: locs[1] = C:/Users/Florian/Source/Workspaces/Arbeitsbereich/FindAndReplacePlugin/com.florian.regexfindandreplace/ which is also the directory of my src-folder and my plugin.xml file. I may mention that my code works if I set as classpath System.getProperty("java.class.path") and if I run it as a JUnit test.

Comment: I am assuming your interface file `IMatchResultEvaluator` in in src folder. then just append src to `locs[1]` like `locs[1] = locs[1]+"/src";` and use it as classpath,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118132/discussion-between-svasa-and-user172501).

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the problem solved. I only compile this class now

```
    public class MyImplClass {
public static String evaluateMatch( MatchResult match ){
 userText 
}
}
```

and then I compile and load this class into the variable clazz of type Class and do this

```
            final Method method = clazz.getMethod("evaluateMatch", MatchResult.class);
            return new IMatchEvaluator()
                    {

                        @Override
                        public String evaluateMatch(MatchResult match) {
                            try {
                                return (String) method.invoke(null, match);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                                return null;
                            }
                        }

                    };
```

If anyone wanted to, he could download my plugin from https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/findreplace-regular-expressions-and-match-evaluators.